# Get path to execution directory of Windows Forms application

Tags: .net, winforms, path, directory

I would like to get the path to the execution directory of a Windows Forms application. (That is, the directory in which the executable is located.)

Does anyone know of a built-in method in .NET to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Application.Current results in an appdomain
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain_members.aspx

Also this should give you the location of the assembly

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

I seem to recall there being multiple ways of getting the location of the application. but this one worked for me in the past atleast (it's been a while since i've done winforms programming :/)

Comment: It should be Application.CurrentDomain.

Comment: This did not appear to work in .NET 4.0, but Application.UserAppDataPath did work.

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Answer (score 69):

In VB.NET

```
Dim directory as String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

In C#

```
string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Comment: The C# location will also work in VB or other languages that don't support the "My" namepsace.

Comment: @Tomas Pajonk, may I suggest changing the c# "FileName" variable to "directory"?

Answer (score 19):

This could help;

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

also here is the [reference](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-application-directory/)

Answer (score 9):

`System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` will solve your problem, I think

Answer (score 2):

Both of the examples are in VB.NET.

**Debug path:**

```
TextBox1.Text = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

**EXE path:**

```
TextBox2.Text = IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string apppath = 
    (new System.IO.FileInfo
    (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).DirectoryName;
```

Comment: Sorry, the Assembly namespace and the code display panel do not play nicely together. I hate scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Management

Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = Path.GetFullPath(Application.ExecutablePath)
        Process.Start(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Main_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    If args.Length > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = Path.GetFullPath(Application.ExecutablePath)
        Process.Start(TextBox1.Text)   
    End If
End Sub
```