# Best way to get application folder path

Tags: c#, .net

I see that there are some ways to get the application folder path:

1. `Application.StartupPath`
2. `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`
3. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
4. `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`
5. `Environment.CurrentDirectory`
6. `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)`
7. `System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(Application.ExecutablePath)`

What is the best way depending on the situation?

Comment: Why we have a lot ways to get application' path. I think there is a reason for each way.

Comment: There is a error in #6: should read: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase),
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)

Comment: hooray for #6, while I'm in a web project, I did not want Server.MapPath logic in my IoC loaded library which is not web-specific in nature

Comment: We now have the reliable `IHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath`, accessed through an injected `IHostEnvironment` dependency (which contains other useful things).

Comment: There is also `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`.

Comment: #4 and #5 are incorrect. They return the current directory, not the directory in which the application is located. (They are sometimes the same, but it's just a coincidence when that's the case.)

Answer (score 691, accepted):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is probably the most useful for accessing files whose location is relative to the application install directory.

In an ASP.NET application, this will be the application root directory, not the bin subfolder - which is probably what you usually want. In a client application, it will be the directory containing the main executable.

In a VSTO 2005 application, it will be the directory containing the VSTO managed assemblies for your application, not, say, the path to the Excel executable.

The others may return different directories depending on your environment - for example see @Vimvq1987's answer.

`CodeBase` is the place where a file was found and can be a URL beginning with http://. In which case `Location` will probably be the assembly download cache. CodeBase is not guaranteed to be set for assemblies in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache).

**UPDATE**
These days (.NET Core, .NET Standard 1.3+ or .NET Framework 4.6+) it's better to use `AppContext.BaseDirectory` rather than `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.  Both are equivalent, but [multiple AppDomains are no longer supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable).

Comment: When testing in Windows XP 32bit, it returns where the shortcut started.

Comment: +1 @Joe and For VSTO document-level add-in see [**THIS**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809950/how-do-i-assign-a-relative-path-of-an-embed-image-to-a-activesheet-pagesetup-lef)

Comment: Be aware that this returns a path with a backslash at the end. This caused me problems when formatting a string with the result to pass as a process argument.

Comment: @avenmore - If you're formatting a string to build a path, consider using `Path.Combine` instead.  This will take care of the trailing backslash for you.

Comment: @joe: It was just a gotcha when using "args = string.Format("-p\"{0}\" -sFalse -lTrue", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);" - results in an unescaped quote. Used Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) to trim it.

Comment: Just pointing out the solution for a ASP.NET bin folder is:
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
Note however, it will be prefixed with "file:\\" (which can be fixed with [.Replace("file:\\", "")]).

Comment: This is returning the bin/debug folder for me in VS 2017, not the root directory.

Comment: @SmoveBB - what's the project type?  `bin\debug` is the folder containing the executable

Comment: @Joe, for .NET Core 2.2, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory => "SLN_FOLDER\PROJ_FOLDER\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\"

Comment: Running command line from %USERPROFILE% folder. Program is at D:\somwhere-else\program.exe, `AppContext.BaseDirectory` This code return different locations.
On build, it returns bin\Release\net5.0. On publish it returns temporary folder.

Comment: This is not working when project built with "IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract" option.

Answer (score 132):

1. `Application.StartupPath`and 7. `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` - Is only going to work for [Windows Forms application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

   Is going to give you something like: `"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\legal-services\\e84f415e\\96c98009\\assembly\\dl3\\42aaba80\\bcf9fd83_4b63d101"` which is where the page that you are running is.
3. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` for web application could be useful and will return something like `"C:\\hg\\Services\\Services\\Services.Website\\"` which is base directory and is quite useful.
4. `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and  5. `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

will get you location of where the process got fired from - so for web app running in debug mode from Visual Studio something like `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express"`

6. `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)`

will get you location where `.dll` that is running the code is, for web app that could be `"file:\\C:\\hg\\Services\\Services\\Services.Website\\bin"`

Now in case of for example console app points 2-6 will be directory where `.exe`  file is.

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: Fairly sure wanting the "current folder" is only relevant for non-web apps anyway...

Answer (score 64):

Note that not all of these methods will return the same value. In some cases, they can return the same value, but be careful, their purposes are different:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

returns the `StartupPath` parameter (can be set when run the application)

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

returns the current directory, which may or may not be the folder where the application is located. The same goes for `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. In case you are using this in a DLL file, it will return the path of where the process is running (this is especially true in ASP.NET).

Comment: Please please please don't use `GetCurrentDirectory()`, for the love of running things from different paths! :(

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck you didn't put your reasons for the previous question.

Answer (score 11):

For a web application, to get the current web application root directory, generally call by web page for the current incoming request:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath();

System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

[Above code description](http://iisfault.blogspot.com/2015/06/application-current-folder-in-aspnet-c.html)

Answer (score 10):

I started a process from a Windows Service over the Win32 API in the session from the user which is actually logged in (in Task Manager session 1 not 0). In this was we can get to know, which variable is the best.

For all 7 cases from the question above, the following are the results:

```
Path1: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram
Path2: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram
Path3: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\
Path4: C:\Windows\system32
Path5: C:\Windows\system32
Path6: file:\C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram
Path7: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram
```

Perhaps it's helpful for some of you, doing the same stuff, when you search the best variable for your case.

Comment: Very relevant answer. So many people forget that "working directory" != "program directory".

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, the best way is a combination of these.

1. `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase`
   Will give you the bin folder
2. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`
   Works fine on .Net Core but not .Net and will give you the root directory of the project
3. `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
   Works fine in .Net but not .Net core and will give you the root directory of the project

In a class library that is supposed to target.Net and .Net core I check which framework is hosting the library and pick one or the other.

Comment: Re "*will give you the root directory of the project*", No, it gives the current directory, which could by any directory

Answer (score 3):

To get the path to `.exe` for simple desktop applications I use

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

which returns path to `.exe`.
Also be aware that for several domains the `.exe` for default domain will be returned, or the `.exe` executed by first call of `ExecuteAssembly(String)` and that **if the entry is unmanaged**, the **`null`** will be returned.

Be careful with `GetExecutingAssembly()`, naming was confusing for me, as I have expected to get the `.exe`, but it returns the `.dll` or `.exe`, where the code is placed, so in case of `GetExecutingAssembly()` **placed in library** it returns the library.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this one successfully

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
```

It works even inside [linqpad.](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: this is missing the opening bracket of GetCurrentProcess. btw it evaluates to C:\Program Files\dotnet in my .net core project while debugging in visual studio because thats where dotnet.exe is located

Answer (score -1):

this one `System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(Application.ExecutablePath)` changed to `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)`

Answer (score -1):

If you know to get the root directory:

```
string rootPath = Path.GetPathRoot(Application.StartupPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

Root directory:

```
DriveInfo cDrive = new DriveInfo(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory);
var driverPath = cDrive.RootDirectory;
```

Comment: This appears to get the current working directory, while that may be useful sometimes, it is definitely not guaranteed to be the EXE path.

Comment: Exactly. Not exe.path. This is root path