# Hard Coding a Relative Path in C#

Tags: c#

I have an XML file in outside of my project folder, and I want to access it from my code, in order for the code to be executed on whatever machine I would put the path relative to the project's directory.

Lets say as an example that my current directory is in Folder A, and the file I want to access is in Folder B next to A.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path

Comment: The project's directory (as in, the directory of the `.csproj` file) will be irrelevant on the target machine, but the directory of the executable file (the `.exe` file) may be. What *is* the relative path between the executable file and the Xml file?

Comment: Do you have any control on the location of this file? If it is generated from some other application or user action there is always the chance that something changes. Why not use a configuration file and read the exact location there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the XML file is always inside your application folder you can use.

[Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx)

The working path may not necessarily be where the executable file is located. To be sure you can use the following code taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx).

```
string path;
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

Otherwise, if it is part of Microsoft's special folders, like .e.g MyDocuments you can use.

[Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

You would use it like this.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
                                           "myfile.xml")
```

The output would be the path to the myfile.xml in the current users My Documents folder. In my case it would give me `C:\Users\eandersson\Documents\myfile.xml`.

[Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is very helpful here as it will allow us to combine multiple disk paths into one.

**Edit**: *Additional information requested by comment.*

I think the best approach would be to use [Directory.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx).

```
Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName
```

And do something like this.

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName, "PathB", "myfile.xml")
```

This would look for PathB in the same location as your Project Folder.

```
C:\MyProjects\PathA\MyExecutable.exe
C:\MyProjects\PathB\myfile.xml
```

Lets say that you are running `MyExecutable.exe` from that location. The above code should automatically return the second location inside PathB with the file `myfile.xml`.

Comment: lets say my current directory is in Folder A, and the file is in Folder B next to A..how can this solve it?

Comment: Please, let me know if that was what you were looking for. :)

Comment: "If the XML file is always inside your application folder you can use. `Environment.CurrentDirectory`" - wrong. The current working directory doesn't have to be the same as the directory where the application is stored.

Comment: I updated the answer @O.R.Mapper, while it may be a trap, it's only in special scenarios that the executable and working directory will be different.