# Does File.Exists() always search in the same directory as the executable?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check for a file in the same directory as executable.

Presently I am using this code -

```
if (!File.Exists(versionFile))
{
     File.Create(versionFile).Close();        
}
```

And at one place I am using this:

```
string file =     
   Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) 
        + "\\" + args.Executable;
    if (File.Exists(file)) {
        Process.Start(file);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Both are doing the same job but I am not sure which one is more robust. I cannot think of any scenario where either one would fail, but at the same time I have a fishy feeling about both these approaches.

Which one is more robust or is there any other better alternative to this simple problem?

Comment: Why not use `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, versionFile);`?

Comment: Yes but Application.StartupPath is not available in class libraries/console applications. It needs a reference of System.Windows.Forms

Comment: The `winforms` tag tricked me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not doing exactly the same job: the first will look for a file relative to the current working directory, which may not be the same as the second.

Neither is completely robust, since `GetEntryAssembly` can return null if a managed assembly has been loaded from an unmanaged application, and `Assembly.Location` might be the Assembly Dowmload Cache.

[The best solution is to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041505/13087).

Answer (score 3):

First one uses current directory (which can be set by Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dir)), so second approach is more robust than the first one.

Comment: Even if the program doesn't change the current directory, the current directory is not necessarily that of the executable.

Comment: The current directory can also be changed by setting the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` property, `Environment.CurrentDirectory = dir;`. It seems to be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
string startupPath = null;

using (var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
    startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.MainModule.FileName);
}
```

The reason is that is the only one i found reliable until now. As a side note the `Application.StartupPath` do this:

```
public static string StartupPath
{
    get
    {
        if (Application.startupPath == null)
        {
            StringBuilder buffer =
                new StringBuilder(260);
            UnsafeNativeMethods.GetModuleFileName(
                NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
            Application.startupPath =
                Path.GetDirectoryName(((object)buffer).ToString());
        }
        new FileIOPermission(
            FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery,
            Application.startupPath).Demand();
        return Application.startupPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: In some cases have bitten me, like with dinamically loaded assembly.

Comment: "process.MainModule.FileName" may not be accessible if you don't have Full Trust.  Also it's probably not very useful in an ASP.NET application or a VSTO add-in.  Hence AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is probably best.

Comment: You're absolutely right for ASP.NET, but in ASP.NET I use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`.