# System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName makes path invalide

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to execute a tool-exe which is located in the same directory as main exe.
For this I'm trying to obtain first the exe-name of the process using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly and then getting the directory using IO.Path.GetDirectoryName

```
//1
String exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase; 
//2
String ncpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
```

1 returns "file:///C:/Development/RC_trunk/bin/Release/ResultConfirmation.EXE"
It is an URI. Not exactly what I need but ok.

2 returns "file:\C:\Development\RC_trunk\bin\Release" Which seems to be a simple [/]+ to \ replacement.

Am I using wrong API for my problem?

P.S.
IDE is VS2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the application directory, try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Take a look at [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path) for other ways of accessing the directory.

Comment: OK, looks like there are a few possibilities for selecting a wrong one for a newcomer. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [GetExecutingAssembly.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

instead of CodeBase and then use GetDirectoryName.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead for step 1)

```
string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```