# Open file from user setup folder on setup project - C#

Tags: c#, setup-project

I want to create a Setup Project that loads a file from a specific path (the same place of the setup.exe file folder).

I know how to create a setup project and how to load a file from a static folder (like Debug folder).

How can I change it to a dynamic folder / path?

I hope I am explaining well enough?

This is example of what I want to get at the end:
[image]
For now, I only get the .msi and the .exe files, I want to add the .HEX file so when I click on the setup.exe, it finds the file from the same folder.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research for you. [This SO answer will show you an excellent way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041505/3317555) to get the application's base directory. From there you can just append the final folders and plug in the file name.

EDIT: from your comment, I believe that you are looking for this:

`string path = @"C:\C# Projects\SQA-V Flash...";`

From there you can just append the rest of the info. Oh, I put `...` in there because your snapshot doesn't include the entire folder name.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to get the application base directory, I want to get the setup.exe folder(for example setup.exe is located in "C:\New Folder" and the application base folder is "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Project folder") And how can I append it to the Setup Project?

Comment: My typical method for that is to use a string literal that holds the folder you want. I'll edit my answer with a simple one using the path you put in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is installed and running and you now want to know where it was installed from, your setup can create (in the registry view of the setup project) a registry item somewhere and set its value to [SourceDir] and it will resolve to the actual installation source.  Your app can read that item to get the location.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the Answer is this:

In the Application Folder I added the desired file. and than in the properties of the file there is a parameter - **PackageAs"** this parameter by default is "**vsdpaDefault**", change it to "**vsdpaLoose**" and that's it!
It is that easy, but it takes me 1 day to find it :)

Thanks for trying to help!