# How to attach local html file with project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am using **WebBrowser control** in my C# winform application, And in URL property I am giving Path of local html file. Below is the code of of my **PrintAds.Designer.cs**

```
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("D:\\PrintAds.htm", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

Every thing is working fine, But I want to add this html file with the project, and I want to **dynamically** pass the URL to WebBrowser control, How do I do that?

This project is going to be used offline so I cant pass website URL.

Comment: Does it matter if the html file is only in your project folder?

Comment: @Zekth I didn't get it!

Comment: In your example your path is on the D: drive, but you can't access via absolute path in web browser. The way to access HTML file is to pass relative URL ( relative to your project ). The solution may be to copy the html file in a temp folder in your project and access to the copied file via relativ url.

Comment: @Zekth By giving the above path, I can access that html page in my WebBrowser control, But the problem is after installation on another computer manually I need to copy the PrintAds.htm file to D: directory, instead of that I want to bind the file in project and dynamically pass the url to WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to access the HTML file relative to the application root?

In which case can't you just pass something like:

```
var localURL = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "PrintAds.htm");
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri(localURL, System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

(You need to import the System.IO namespace)

The html file itself should be included within the project, in this example in the root  (with a build action as Content)

Please note - Directory.GetCurrentDirectory gets the current working directory - which by default is the application root directory, but can be changed - See the answer at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path) for alternatives