# C# how to get access to folders created in your solution explorer

Tags: c#, windows, solution-explorer

How do you call or use these files you created in your solution explorer

the code that I am using at the moment is:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        { 

            FileName = path + "\\Console\\Hallo\\SWIR\\Dump.exe",//Path is a string that is my current path this is my exe's launch piont
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb ="open"
        });
```

I'm am trying to use them from my solution explorer any help will be appreciated

Comment: ..\\ gives you the directory that is one folder higher up than your current directory

Comment: \\I know i use to work out of the debug folder  so the path i use is the current path from where the exe is launched but i want to let it run from the save folder as resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the location of your current executing assembly, I suggest you use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

[Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path/6041505#6041505)