# Add downloaded images to resource folder

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have downloaded an image with the following code:

```
bool pageExists = false;
// Check if webpage exists
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780" + imagePath);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
      pageExists = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
}

// Download image
if (pageExists)
{
   string localFilename = @"C:\Users\Giri\Desktop\giri" + id + ".jpg";
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
       client.DownloadFile("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780" + imagePath, localFilename);
   }
}
```

For now, I have just been saving this image on my `Desktop`.

My question is how do I go about storing this image in my `WPF` application programmatically within a `resources` folder or a folder I have generated myself? The images should persist in that the next time the application is run, the added images should remain.

Is there an accepted place I should be storing my images?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about getting the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and adding a `Resource` folder to that path and saving the images there.

Comment: Just a note: by using a HttpWebRequest *and* a WebClient you're downloading the image twice. You should use only one of them, preferably the WebClient, because it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks @PiyushParashar. I am currently doing it the way you have suggested. I was wondering, when this application is packaged up and being used by a consumer, will `Environment.CurrentDirectory` still point to the same place? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. Which will give you the directory of your executable. Even in deployed code this should give you the right value. But other values like `Environment.CurrentDirectory` can give different value based on from where you are calling it etc.

See this question  [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)