# How to get executing assembly location?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to access a file from an ASP.Net vNext class library using a relative path. The file is (should be) located in the installation folder of the application, and to build the full path I need to get that folder path.

Using `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, the `Location` property is empty. The `CodeBase` property contains the following:

> CodeBase = "file:///C:/Users/username/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7/bin/Microsoft.Dnx.Loader.dll"

How can I get the actual folder where the files being executed are located?

**EDIT:**
The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in) are not valid for ASP.Net 5 as I explained already. - just for the duplicate flagging.

Comment: Tried using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The answers there are not valid for ASP.Net 5 as I explained in my question. I will test JFM suggestion in the morning.

Comment: You may really want the ASP / IIS / ISAPI  functions behind the Server.MapPath  functions.    These tell you where IIS is running you, not so much where .NET is running from.  The subtle difference is that Server is more like the URL to hard drive relationship  and Reflection is more like the .NET to hard drive relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath`.  You can create a constructor in your `Startup` class that takes this as an argument, get the value there and then make it available to the class library:

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment env)
{
    _location = env.ApplicationBasePath;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are getting an instance of the class that needs the location via DI, you can add "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions" as a dependency in your class library project and add a constructor on the class that takes `IApplicationEnvironment`:

```
public MyClass(IApplicationEnvironment env)
{
    Location = env.ApplicationBasePath;
}
```

---

In a static class try

`ProjectRootResolver.ResolveRootDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());`

`ProjectRootResolver` is in the `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime` namespace.

Comment: Brilliant! :) works like a charm. I had a `using Microsoft.Framework.Runtime` statement before and that failed. `using Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime` works.

Comment: Any idea how to get this in a static class? The static constructor is always parameterless

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou Please see my edit above.  Hope that works for you.

Comment: Just a note: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() can be changed e.g. by calling Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:\New\Current\Directory"). So if you plan to change the current directory save it before.

Comment: `ProjectRootResolver.ResolveRootDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());`was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is probably the most useful for accessing files whose location is relative to the application install directory.

See more at [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still giving `C:\Users\username\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7\bin\`.

Comment: AppDomain does not exist in .NET Core