# embedded database connection string

Tags: c#, connection-string, relative-path, dbase

I got two problems:
First, i'm trying to connect my windows form app with my embedded database (.dbf) and i keep getting this message no matter what i do to the connection string: 
"error isam instalable cant be found"

Second, i would like to make the path relative to the executable.

Thanks, here is the code i'm using to test the whole thing:

```
    private void bGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        string cadena = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =D:\\; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; UserID =; Password =;";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = cadena;
        con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("conected");
        con.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exp.Message); 
        }


    }
```

Comment: Is your application running in 32-bit, or 64-bit mode?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209805

Comment: Well my system is 64-bit but im not sure how to see if my app is running at 32 or 64.
And thanks for the link but i allready saw it and it was not clear enough for me, sorry im still learning.

Answer (score 1):

**For the second part**, you can get the path of your executable using System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(Application.ExecutablePath). There are more ways do this based upon your need (see [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)).

Comment: string app = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

string cadena = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source ="+app+"; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; UserID =; Password =;";

I'm trying this now but i does not work also if i use GetDirectory instead of GetDirectoryName it gives me an error. Thanks for the answer tho

Answer (score 0):

To avoid further difficulties instead of 
'OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();'
 try

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection())
{
    ; // your command and executes here
}
```

this way you call the dispose / close method always (using generally wraps up your code so that the part between { and } is wrapped in a try / catch block with finally that calls a dispose() / close() on the OleDbConn object.