# Finding a folder

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a windows form application, and I want to create a check for a folder, which I know how to do, but I don't want it to be

"C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\This Project\Required Files\file.txt"

But

"This Project\Required Files\file.txt"

is that possible?
I need to do this because I want to app to be portable, and if I put the whole path starting with C and the app is installed somewhere else (For EG. C:\User\Bob\Application\Required Files\file.txt")
Thanks.

Comment: Put the folder in `Users` or `Program Data` depending on how you use it.  If you make it a child of the app install folder you may not have permission to the data file at run time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like.
For example you a folder the has 2 sub-folders

1.My Program

2.Required Files

The folder `My Program` contains your program `.exe` for example

and the folder `Required Files` has the `files.txt`

you can do something like this in your code.

```
Dim path as string = App.Path & "\Required Files\file.txt"
```

so what will happen is that whereever your program will installed the `Required File` folder will follow. The `App.Path` will create the rest of the folder location + the assigned folder that you have and that is `"\Required Files\file.txt"`

See? Relationship goals hahaha kidding.

I didnt see that you have another folder called `Project` you just do this.

`Dim path as string = App.Path & "Project\Required Files\file.txt"`

I hope this one helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use `Application.StartupPath`. Or split the complete path and take the records at the position that you want.

```
Dim Path() as string = application.StartupPath().split("\"c)
```

Check Path() in a debug and take what you need.