# Dynamic file paths and Image command

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a file path, at the end of which will be a "images" folder that the program will use with the Image command to load jpeg files.
I want the program to dynamically know to load the jpeg files from the image folder where ever the executable is launched.
I was able to find this on this site, I added the 2 bottom code lines:

```
public static string AssemblyDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            return System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }

    public static string imagePath = @"\images";
    public static string finalImagePath = AssemblyDirectory + imagePath;
```

If I set a break point, the 'finalImagePath' is:
"C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Universal Serial Diagnostics\bin\Debug\images"

Which is correct, but how do I incorporate that with:

```
     Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\Dip\ENV500008.jpg");
```

Replacing the hard coded path with the dynamic path.
The ENV500008.jpg would be stored in the images folder.
Thank you.

Comment: I believe that you are looking for Path.GetFileName; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx. And then concatenate with finalImagePath.

Comment: The top code gets the path, how do I replace the variable "finalImagePath" and use that with the Image.FromFile command?

Comment: Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\Dip\ENV500008.jpg");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path

Comment: Do you want it to be `C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Universal Serial Diagnostics\bin\Debug\images\ENV500008.jpg`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. What is the role of the path contained in Image.FromFile....?

Comment: I figured it out, this is what I was looking for:

Comment: Image image = Image.FromFile(@finalImagePath+"\\ENV500008.jpg");

Comment: Basically, I want an Images folder (contains just JPEG files) that are stored in same direectory as the .EXE file. So If a user moves the EXE file and the image folder to another directory, the program dynamically updates the path to the Images folder. Does that make any sense?

Comment: or you can just add the image as resource in the executable https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQMDsJgMXhE

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ENV500008.jpg";

if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
    // .. the rest of the code that uses the image .. 
}
```

Comment: While that would work, since I have about 100 images to display, I'm using:

Comment: Image image = Image.FromFile(@finalImagePath + "\\ENV500008.jpg");

            Image image5 = Image.FromFile(@finalImagePath + "\\ENV510829-2.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

```
       Image image = Image.FromFile(@finalImagePath + "\\ENV500008.jpg");

        Image image5 = Image.FromFile(@finalImagePath + "\\ENV510829-2.jpg");
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: OK, 1) I was trying to dynamically find the path to my EXE file. Which I found the answer to on this website. 2) Once I know the path, I created an 'images' folder that has about 100 JPEG files. Where I was having difficulty was in the use of the IMAGE image - Image.FromFile(path) code.  So I posted the above question. Meanwhile I kept playing around with it. I finally answered my own question. I was trying to make my code work in a way that if a user moved the EXE file and images folder, the program would still work.

Comment: I have since moved to VS2015 and am now embedding the JPEG files as a resource, larger file size of the exe, but I don't have to worry about users moving the JPEG files. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add all this information into the post itself and not just as comments. Details in post is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```css
public static string GetAnyPath(string fileName)
{
            //my path where i want my file to be created is : "C:\\Users\\{my-system-name}\\Desktop\\Me\\create-file\\CreateFile\\CreateFile\\FilesPosition\\firstjson.json"
            var basePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath.Split(new string[] { "\\CreateFile" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
            var filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, $"CreateFile\\CreateFile\\FilesPosition\\{fileName}.json");
            return filePath;
}
```

change .json to any type according to need
refer :https://github.com/swinalkm/create-file/tree/main/CreateFile/CreateFile