# How to download file to a sepcific folder in project C#

Tags: c#, download, webclient

When I try to download an excel file using C# Web client  the default saved location is the bin folder

```
  public void downloadCSVResult(string ssid,string thoken)
    {


        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ssid, thoken);
            string url= "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+ssid+"/SMS/Messages.csv";
            client.DownloadFile("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+ssid+"/SMS/Messages.csv", "Messages.csv");

        }
        Process.Start(@"\\SMSLogs");
```

I have added a folder called SMSLogs inside the project and I want to download to this specific folder

But When I try to download and to open the folder using explorer :

```
client.DownloadFile("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+ssid+"/SMS/Messages.csv", "SMSLogs\\Messages.csv");

        }
        Process.Start(@"\\SMSLogs");
```

I receive an error

> {"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\SMSLogs\Messages.csv'."}

But I don't want to save it in the C: directory because once I give the application to the client , It be good to have a directory called SMSLogs and inside of it the excel file

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @David wrong path : SMSLogs\\Messages.csv

Comment: @David Edited the error message

Comment: You must create the folder if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.
Here is a good reference for routing to the base folder in an application: [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path).

```
 string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\SMSLogs\";
```