# How to get root directory of project in asp.net core. Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() doesn't seem to work correctly on a mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My project has a folder structure to the tune of:

- Project,
- Project/data
- Project/Engine
- Project/Server
- project/front-end

In the server (running in the Project/Server folder) I refer to the folder like this:

```
var rootFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
rootFolder = rootFolder.Substring(0,
            rootFolder.IndexOf(@"\Project\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + @"\Project\".Length);
PathToData = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(rootFolder, "Data"));

var Parser = Parser();
var d = new FileStream(Path.Combine(PathToData, $"{dataFileName}.txt"), FileMode.Open);
var fs = new StreamReader(d, Encoding.UTF8);
```

On my windows machine this code works fine since `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` reffered to the current folder, and doing

```
rootFolder.Substring(0, rootFolder.IndexOf(@"\Project\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + @"\Project\".Length);
```

gets me the root folder of the project (not the bin or debug folders). 
But when I ran it on a mac it got "`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`" sent me to /usr//[something else]. It didn't refer to the folder where my project lies.

What is the correct way to find relative paths in my project? Where should I store the data folder in a way that it is easily accessible to all the sub projects in the solution - specifically to the kestrel server project? I prefer to not have to store it in the wwwroot folder because the data folder is maintained by a different member in the team, and I just want to access the latest version. What are my options?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Depending on where you are in the kestrel pipeline - if you have access to `IConfiguration` (*`Startup.cs` constructor*) or `IWebHostEnvironment` (*formerly `IHostingEnvironment`*) you can either inject the `IWebHostEnvironment` into your constructor or just request the key from the configuration.

#### Inject `IWebHostEnvironment` in `Startup.cs` Constructor

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
     var contentRoot = env.ContentRootPath;
}
```

#### [Using IConfiguration in Startup.cs Constructor](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/1.0.0-rc2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/WebHostDefaults.cs#L15)

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
     var contentRoot = configuration.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey);
}
```

Comment: you can probably inject IConfiguration in to the controller, and get what you need from that. right?

Comment: how can we access contentRoot in Startup ?

Comment: IHostingEnvironment is now obsolete int Core , and replaced by IWebHostEnvironment

Comment: @AntonioRodríguez - updated to reflect, `IWebHostEnvironment` implements `IHostEnvironment` - [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - [`IHostingEnvironment` has been retired](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602187/175679)

Comment: this works for me to be able to get the local server disk path, but how can I get the hosting domain-to-the-file path?

Answer (score 86):

*Working on .Net Core 2.2 and 3.0 as of now.*

To get the projects root directory within a **Controller:**

- Create a property for the hosting environment

  ```
  private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
  ```
- Add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting to your controller

  ```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
  ```
- Register the service in the constructor

  ```
  public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) {
      _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
  }
  ```
- Now, to get the projects root path

  ```
  string projectRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
  ```

To get the "**wwwroot**" path, use

```
_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath
```

Comment: This approached worked fine for .Net Core 2.2 as well

Comment: as want to get the file path in development mode mean while run the project from visual studio "_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath" and "hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath" both returns the null. what should i do to get the file path

Comment: @maliksaifullah check that your `wwwroot` is there in the project and that it isn't empty.

Comment: @maliksaifullah Can you show me your controller where you're trying to get the path?

Comment: @maliksaifullah Are you registering the service in the controller? I don't think the `IHostingEvironment` is injected using dependency injection here and that's the problem.

Comment: yes i am registering it like this
.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(new HostingEnvironment())

and yes injecting it as dependency injection https://imgur.com/a/tRYvTTw

Comment: anyone else running into the problem that @maliksaifullah had, MAKE SURE you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` written in the Startup class Configure method. This enables the use of static files - wwwroot folder.

Comment: Use `IHostEnvironment` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` instead. See [Announcement: IHostingEnvironment's and IApplicationLifetime's marked obsolete and replaced](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7749).

Answer (score 48):

In some cases `_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` and `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` targets to source directory. Here is [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/589) about it.

The solution proposed there helped me

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: All .NET Core application is a Console.

Comment: In a Core app this returned "...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp\" and not the root project folder as expected.

Comment: @Roberto Root project folder for net core apps should not be returned. This is a correct behavior.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC Core 3 or newer, `IHostingEnvironment` has been deprecated and replaced with `IWebHostEnvironment`

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
{
    var webRootPath = webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
}
```

Comment: Technically, I believe `IHostingEnvironment` was replaced by `IHostEnvironment`. `IWebHostEnvironment` is a more specific variant, specific to web hosts. Library projects (arguably even your own solution's class libraries) would probably do well to avoid a dependency on `IWebHostEnvironment`, since they cannot guarantee that they will be run in a _web_ host.

Answer (score 23):

As previously answered (and retracted). To get the *base* directory, as in the location of the running assembly, don't use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), rather get it from IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath.

```
private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private string projectRootFolder;
    public Program(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = env;
        projectRootFolder = env.ContentRootPath.Substring(0,
            env.ContentRootPath.LastIndexOf(@"\ProjectRoot\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + @"\ProjectRoot\".Length);
    }
```

However I made an additional error: I had set the ContentRoot Directory to Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() at startup undermining the default value which I had so desired!
Here I commented out the offending line:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
           // .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //<== The mistake
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Program>()
            .Build();
        host.Run();
    }
```

Now it runs correctly - I can now navigate to sub folders of my projects root with:

```
var pathToData = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(projectRootFolder, "data"));
```

I realised my mistake by reading [BaseDirectory vs. Current Directory](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/370e35/basedirectory-vs-currentdirectory-in-C-Sharp/) and @CodeNotFound founds answer (which was retracted because it didn't work because of the above mistake) which basically can be found here: [Getting WebRoot Path and Content Root Path in Asp.net Core](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/22/getting-the-web-root-path-and-the-content-root-path-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: FYI if you are wondering how to get IHostingEnvironment in Startup class: add it as constructor argument.

Answer (score 22):

Try looking here: [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)

To quote from there:

> `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns the current
>   directory, which may or may not be the folder where the application is
>   located. The same goes for Environment.CurrentDirectory. In case you
>   are using this in a DLL file, it will return the path of where the
>   process is running (this is especially true in ASP.NET).

Answer (score 18):

I solved the problem with this code:

```
using System.IO;

var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Substring(0, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.IndexOf("bin\\")))
```

Comment: An answer that actually is understandable and works. thanks!

Comment: Please do not use this answer as it hardcodes `bin` which might not be present!

Answer (score 9):

I test and compare on asp.net core 6, I think this can help someone.

Assume your project location path is `D:\Project\Server`, if you use linux or mac just replace `\` to `/`.

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
IWebHostEnvironment environment = app.Environment;

System.Console.WriteLine(environment.ContentRootPath);
// D:\Project\Server\
System.Console.WriteLine(environment.WebRootPath);
// D:\Project\Server\wwwroot

System.Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
// D:\Project\Server\bin\Debug\net6.0
System.Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase));
// file:\D:\Project\Server\bin\Debug\net6.0
System.Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
// D:\Project\Server\bin\Debug\net6.0

System.Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
// D:\Project\Server
System.Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
// D:\Project\Server\bin\Debug\net6.0\
System.Console.WriteLine(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
// D:\Project\Server\bin\Debug\net6.0\
```

Note: If `environment.WebRootPath` is empty string, you need create `wwwroot` folder in root project, then everything work fine.

Answer (score 6):

If using the `IWebHostEnvironment` via DI is not an option for you, use

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: Not sure why both options are giving different values. The correct one I seek was the BaseDirectory. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If that can be useful to anyone, in a Razor Page cshtml.cs file, here is how to get it: add an `IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment` parameter to the constructor and it will be injected automatically:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly IHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment; // has ContentRootPath property
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

PS: `IHostEnvironment` is in `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` namespace, in `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll` ... what a mess!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Henrique A technique and supports Unit Test contexts as well...

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> appPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Replace("YOURTestProject", "YOUR");
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(appPath.Slice(0, appPath.IndexOf("bin\\")));
string path = Path.Combine(dir.ToString(), "Resources", "countries.dat");
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    countries = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace app.Controllers;

public class TestController: Controller
{

  private readonly IHostEnvironment _env;
  private readonly string _rootPath;

  public ProductController(IHostEnvironment env)
  {
    _env = env;
    _rootPath = _env.ContentRootPath;
  }

}
```

Here `IHostingEnvironment env` this parameter will be passed to the controller's constructor method, that `env` is similar to the `process.env` in `nodejs`

So, we are storing that `env` to our controller property `_env` [Note: `_` is used because this is a convention or good practice for private class properties]

Now we have a property `ContentRootPath: string` in that `_env` variable that returns the absolute path to the root directory where your dotnet mvc is stored.

So, now we are storing that path to another `string` variable `_rootPath`

`_rootPath = _env.ContentRootPath`

Some of you maybe familiar with `this.something` but in C# using `this` is not required

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just setting the "Working directory" in rider's debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net 6.0

> program.cs

```
IWebHostEnvironment environment = builder.Environment;
environment.ContentRootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // <-- output: *\ProjectName\bin\Debug\net6.0\
```

> In Home controller

```
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;

        string fullPath = _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

> It seems IHostingEnvironment has been replaced by IHostEnvironment
>   (and a few others). You should be able to change the interface type in
>   your code and everything will work as it used to :-)
>
> You can find more information about the changes at this link on GitHub
>   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7749
>
> EDIT There is also an additional interface IWebHostEnvironment that
>   can be used in ASP.NET Core applications. This is available in the
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting namespace.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602187/932448

Comment: This is a literal copy & paste from another answer. You should flag the question as a duplicate, not copy content.