# ASPNet Core - macOS dev can't find appsettings and wwwroot

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm starting a new project with a friend, I will be using windows and he works on macOS.

The project uses EntityFrameworkCore and I configure the connection string as this (inside the context class):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

> `configuration` is an injected service of type `IConfiguration`.

In windows this works perfectly but mac fails saying that it can't use "null" as value. `GetConnectionString` is indeed returning null for mac.

I found many places saying that I need to use `UseContentRoot` in the program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

But it doesn't work on mac anyway.

Also, in macOS `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will return `<ProjectRoot>/bin/debug/net462` and windows will return `<ProjectRoot>`.

So I assume that it doesn't find `appsettings.json` inside that path and therefore it fails.

I also checked if I could access wwwroot and I can't. It's always using the `bin` instead of project root.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

**PS**

Different from the question tagged as "duplicate from":

> There he isn't using UseContentRoot and neither IConfiguration to retrieve a > connectionString. I've seen that and it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get root directory of project in asp.net core. Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() doesn't seem to work correctly on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709657/how-to-get-root-directory-of-project-in-asp-net-core-directory-getcurrentdirect)

Comment: @KirkLarkin, it's different. There he isn't using `UseContentRoot` and neither IConfiguration to retrieve a `connectionString`. I've seen that and it doesn't work.