# File upload to wwwroot folder in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Why is my following codes sometimes work, but sometimes it does't work?

```
 private bool UploadFile(IFormFile ufile, string fname)
 {
     if (ufile.Length > 0)
     {
          string fullpath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, fname);
          using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Create))
          {
               ufile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
          }
          return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

The code did managed to save the picture to a folder which I created under `wwwroot`, but the picture is not appearing, and even in Visual Studio too.

Is there a way to solve it?

Thanks.

Even when I open up the file explorer of the folder that is storing the pictures, the picture is like is there but not showing any image.

Comment: do you have any solutions that you'd like to share with?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core/49399105#49399105)

Comment: there is a property >> "Show all files" in visual studio solution explorer toolbar. Click to view not include files which then be available to view.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini That is not correct. The `WebRootPath` *is* the `wwwroot` while `ContentRootPath` would be the location you set as the IIS root for the application.

Comment: *“but sometimes it does't work”* – What exactly doesn’t work? Check your logs to see what is going on. And try debugging to see what might go wrong there.

Comment: @poke, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 21):

Try as follows. File will be uploaded to `images` folder under `wwwroot` folder.

```
private async Task<bool> UploadFile(IFormFile ufile)
{
     if (ufile != null && ufile.Length > 0)
     {
          var fileName = Path.GetFileName(ufile.FileName);
          var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images", fileName);
          using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
          {
              await ufile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
          }
          return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: May I know what does "await ufile.CopyToAsync(fileSteam)" means?

Comment: This is an asynchronous method which copy the `FileStream` to the specified path

Comment: But what is the difference between upload the image files to wwwroot/images and wwwroot/myFolder?

Comment: No difference but I have just used a sample name as `images`. You can also use your named folder like :  `var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\yourfolderaname", fileName);`

Comment: @Matt Any update? Whether your problem has been solved or not!

Comment: Nope... still trying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186753/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-matt).

Comment: Please do not use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` inside of your code. Use the hosting environment to retrieve the location of the content root.

Comment: @poke Thank you! but any explanation please?

Comment: Instead using GetCurrentDirectory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709657/how-to-get-root-directory-of-project-in-asp-net-core-directory-getcurrentdirect

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem with dot net core, here's what I did:

-Make virtual directory

-Map it to that folder path (inside wwwroot)

-Make your `fullpath` equals to this VD ; absolute path (can keep it in config file)

-Give write permissions for this folder to iisuser

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, do you have screenschots for each steps that you don't mind sharing with me?

Answer (score 0):

allow accessing to static files, just add this line in you startup.cs file under Configure method:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: "_but the picture is not appearing_" you mean it is not appearing in the internet browser? or you don't see it at all even when you browse manually in file browser?

Comment: But sometimes it does show itself. Is this something to do with the settings or the codes?

Comment: actually saying "_sometimes_" is not clear enough to know the reason, it could be the file size or type which is preventing the file from being saved. Just do more precise tests to find when the files are saved and when they are not, then it can be easy to solve.