# Loading files from current project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to load a json file while mocking an api for testing purposes in a test project.The mock will be loading the json.

[image]

I am currently using `File.ReadAllText` and i have tried the following

`System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(), "bank_response.json")`

`System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\bank_response.json");`

I am getting either the path to bin or null.

Comment: The json file might be in your bin folder. You need to include it in the compilation files

Comment: I don't want to put in bin directory as i am running my test suite and the json is part of the project itself

Comment: If you are testing a Web API, you can use `ContentRootPath` variable, You can inject `IHostingEnvironment` to retrieve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293454/1504370

Comment: Did you set for `bank_response.json` file in properties to be copied to output directory?

`File Properties -> Copy to Output Directory -> Copy always`

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin he seems that he does not want to copy it...

Comment: So the json file is actually a shortcut to somewhere else on the file system?
Why don't you want to output it to the bin directory, since you reference it anyway?

Comment: The issue is that your app isn't running from the project directory; it runs from the bin directory, because that's where the compiled app goes after build. Therefore, files you want to reference relative to your app root *also* need to be copied to bin as part of the build. That's how things work. You'd have the same issue after publishing.

Comment: @billybob doesn't `ContentRootPath` point to build folder as well where won't be json file, because it not included (UPD: what @chris-pratt said)?

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin and @Chris Pratt i forgot about the copy to output settings.Thanks for reminding and btw `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` worked for me since my app isn't a console but a API.