# How to get Physical Path for virtual path in .NET 6 RC1?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

The question is related to Blazor wasm hosted App.

I am resolving `_webHostingEnvironment` in constructor of the controller.

```
_webHostingEnvironment = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
```

I am running into issue where I don't get correct value for the virtual director's physical path.

My app generates a QR code which I need to store in the images folder of virtual directory.

```cs
var webRootPath = "";
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_webHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath))
     webRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
else
   webRootPath = _webHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath
```

Firstly `_webHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` is always `null`, hence the code always gets the path from `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` provides the path of Server, but not the actual deployed path of wwwroot which is further down like /bin/debug/net6.0/wwwroot.

Here is the screenshot of the code in question

[image]

Now I could append that static path to get full path, but no sure what to use when I deploy it on Azure App Service or while using other deployment models

Comment: Blazor WASM runs on the browser. There's no virtual path, much less a physical path. Do you have a *hosted* project? In that case, is the question how to get the `WebRoot` in one of your controllers? Where does `_webHostingEnvironment` come from? That's not something that can be cached. If `WebRootPath` is empty, don't assume .NET Core is broken. Something is wrong with your application and `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will almost certainly return the wrong path.

Comment: I did mention it is Blazor wasm hosted app
The code in question is running inside Server controller.
I do get ContentRootPath, but it is same as GetCurrentDirectory, which is way off from the Virtual Path

Comment: Which means the question has nothing to do with Blazor. Post your ASP.NET Core code. Where did `_webHostingEnvironment`? Which .NET 6 version are you using? Does this code run in a controller? `Startup`? Are you using minimal APIs ?

Comment: I am resolving that in constructor of the controller.
_webHostingEnvironment = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

Comment: Post your code in the question itself, *and* your service registration code. You shouldn't have to use *any* of the code you posted, which means something weird is going on. As [this asnwer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59305508/134204) you won't get a `WebRootPath` if there's no `wwwroot` in the template, although you'll get a `ContentRootPath`. You shouldn't use *either* though. Modifying the contents of your web site's root is a security risk. In ASP.NET Core you can specify multiple file providers and serve/store files from them

Comment: Or you can specify a storage folder in configuration settings, and inject it into controllers, just like any other setting.

Comment: Post the *code*, not a screenshot of the code. Images can't be copied, compiled or googled