# How do I keep my application's working directory consistent even when being run from a batch file?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, relative-path, delete-file

When passing a relative path to [`File.Delete()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netframework-4.7), it tries to delete a file relative to the current working directory as returned by [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.7). However, if my application is run from a batch file, it seems that the current directory refers to the location of the batch file instead of my application. How do I get it to refer to my application's directory consistently, whether it's run from a batch file or directly from the application's exe?

Comment: What about [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx)?

Comment: Don't use a relative path... :)

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I belive that `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returns where the executing assembly is *currently* located, which may or may not be where the assembly is located when not executing. In the case of shadow copying assemblies, you will get a path in a temp directory. `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` will return the 'permenant' path of the assembly

Comment: @RufusL, yes, you are right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application#comment9462946_837501

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria :)

Comment: If I don't use relative paths then how do I make an application that can still run if its folder is moved?

Comment: Okay, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application recommends `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` saying `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` can be changed at runtime. But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path recommends `BaseDirectory`, saying `CodeBase` is not guaranteed to be set for assemblies in the GAC.