# Access appsettings.json from .NET 4.5.2 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two projects, a 1.1.0 ASP.NET Core project and a reference to a 4.5.2 project.

I want to get values from the appsettings.json file to my 4.5.2 project. The appsettings.json file is in the core project.

Tried this from my 4.5.2 project with no luck:

```
var mailServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"];
```

How can I access the values from my 4.5.2 project?

Answer (score 16):

`ConfigurationManager` works with XML-based configuration files that have [specific format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229687(v=vs.90).aspx) and doesn't know how to read the custom JSON file.

Cause you use `appsettings.json` for the ASP.NET Core project as well, you may add dependencies to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json) packages and read settings using ".NET Core approach":

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddJsonFile(@"<path to appsettings.json>");

var configuration = builder.Build();
//  configuration["MailServer"]
```

---

Of course, as `appsettings.json` is a simple JSON file, you may always directly deserialize using any JSON provider.

Comment: Using SetBasePath is necessary in my case
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile(filepath);

Comment: Note that Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() will just return the windows folder usually... Better to use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to get the actual application path (more info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path/6041505)

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration is not available for .net framework 4.5

Answer (score 8):

Nicely done ***"Johann Medina"***, but you forgot to explain a little bit your solution in order people can understand better the idea. I have done it the same way, but here it's the full explanation in order to use it this way...

**appsetting.JSON example:**

```
{
    "Email": {
        "Host": "smtp.office365.com",
        "Port": "587",
        "From": "user@domain.com",
        "Username": "user@domain.com",
        "Password": "IsAAbbUaa22YTHayTJKv44Zfl18BClvpAC33Dn5p4s="
    }
}
```

**POCO class example:**

```
namespace AppSettingsTest
{
    public class AppSettings
    {
        public Email Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Getting appsetting.JSON content example:**

```
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/appsettings.json")) {
        var appSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppSettings>(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

NOTE: Just make sure to set "Copy always" in the property option "Copy to Output Directory" to the JSON file.

Happy Coding!

Comment: much better answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/appsettings.json"))
    Settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: What about it??