# Is there any standard way to load array from appSettings.config file in .NET 4.6.1

Tags: appsettings, configurationmanager, .net-4.6.1

I have a setting like this in my `appSettings.config` file

```
<add key="logFilesLocations" value="[firstfile,secondfile]"/>
```

Is there any standard way to read these values as arrays directly?

I know I can play with the string after reading the value and split string to get the array, but that is ugly.

I tried this also

```
public static List<string> LogFilesLocations => (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("logFilesLocations") ?? Array.Empty<string>()).ToList();
```

But this actually does not return an array.

Comment: No built-in way as long as I know, other than parse the string afterwards. Or using a whole different format with more options, like XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057375/804517

So I replaced `appSettings.config` with `appSettings.json` and put my setting like this

```
"logFilesLocations": [
        "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Logs",
        "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Logs2"
    ]
```

and started reading the values like this

```
public static List<string> LogFilesLocations => _config.GetSection("logFilesLocations").Get<List<string>>();
```

As suggested in the answer I had to add `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` packages