# Embedding .exe's into a VB.net application

Tags: vb.net, path, installation

So here's whats up, 
    I am a Bench Technician for an IT company. I find myself repeating the same task over and over when preforming system reloads. I want to write an application where I have all the programs for a reload in one spot, and call them by a button click event. I have tried adding them into the Resources and calling them by Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\Path" to no avail,  I get " System cannot find the file specified. When the path is hard coded it works like a charm, but this will obviously not do as it needs to be able to move to any system. I am looking for a way to add the exe's I need and a generic way to call the path. I am not looking for handouts here, I have done my homework on this one and still not found a solution,  If I could get someone to -point me in the right direction, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you have already tried is much saner and easier for the average user to work with than having the files embedded in another executable, I'll explain that method.
`CurrentDirectory` is where your executable is executed from, Like this:

```
C:\MyDir> MyOtherDir\MyProgram.exe
```

`CurrentDirectory` refers to `C:\MyDir` in this example.

What you need is the application directory; and according to top answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path) the most reliable way to get that is using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

**EDIT:** Also consider using `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead of `\`.

Comment: Nice answer! Though I would recommend [**`Path.Combine()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of regular string concatenation, for example: `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyFile.exe")` (it also uses `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` internally)