# Virtual path to physical path

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to define a virtual path that will be related to a physical path  in windows .Net application (c#).
In addition, the physical path will change according to the requirements.

f.e

Define a virtual path: `c:\VirtualPath` in code,
and this path will be related each time to a different path - `c:\AppName\1` or `c:\AppName\2` etc.

Which functions need to use in order to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)

Comment: Making this obscure is not a good idea.  Use Project > Properties > Settings or use a command line argument if the required path changes frequently.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). You need to ask about your problem rather than your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If I understand your question correctly it sounds more like a windows question than a c#/dotnet one.)

In Windows, you can use [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) to create virtual links. Also look at [`junction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/hard-links-and-junctions).