# how to read a file from a different project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

**how to read a file from a different project?**

I have a solution:

```
Solution1
-MyProject
-MyProject.Artifacts
----Message.XML
-MyProject.Tests
```

I am attempting to read the contents of `Message.XML` from `MyProject.Tests`.

**How do I read the contents of `Message.XML` from `MyProject.Tests`?**

Unfortunately, right now I'm doing something like this, but it's not very pretty:

```
        var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var parentDir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(currentDir).FullName).FullName;
        var parentParentDir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(currentDir).FullName).FullName).FullName;
        var parentParentParentDir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(currentDir).FullName).FullName).FullName).FullName;
```

Comment: What kind of application is it? Web, Console or WPF ...? I think you can define the XML output folder yourself. Thus, you can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path

Comment: its an azure function

Answer (score 0):

You can store a path to the file in app settings of app.config / web.config using that read the file contents.

That way if you need to deploy your software in a different way you have the flexibility

Comment: then i will need to maintain two sets of configuration files, one in my regular project and one in my tests project

Comment: Or us a config transform so when you run test you get set of values and run production you get a different set

Answer (score -1):

If your path is fixed, you can write the path like "c:\projects\solution ... Message.xml"

If you want a relative path, the simplest way is this:

```
var DI = new DirectoryInfo("..\\..\\..\\..\\Your Folder\\Message.XML");
```

This path is started from CurrentDirectory and goes four folders up and the one folder down and finds the file.