# Using 3rd party dll containing "Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()" in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I'm having an ASP.NET api site, using a group of 3rd party dlls, while running in unit test is fine, in w3wp it is not.

(Edit: these dlls are referenced by one of my module projects, which is dynamically loaded by my ASP site when launching. So I just dump all these 3rd party dlls into the ASP site *bin* folder, it worked fine for other modules with other 3rd party dlls)

After debugging through decompiled code, I found out that one of the dll is using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` dynamically loading some other dlls.

Except that, instead of my website *bin* folder, it gets a location located in *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\my_asp_project\...* where the dll is all by itself.

Is there a way I can avoid this without modifying the dlls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)

Comment: @ManojChoudhari : no, the code used to get application folder path is from 3rd party dll, I don't want to modify that.

Comment: If the third party DLL uses Asembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location - i believe it might not have been intended for ASP.Net usage as per description given on that other thread.