# Can't find JSON file in current directory - Folder not being added in build

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON file which is stored within a folder in my .NET windows forms project.

Deserialize from file:

```
private HashSet<string> swearWords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HashSet<string>>(File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Folder\file.json"));
```

I get the error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'C:..\Prototypes\Prototype1\Prototype1\bin\Debug\Folder\file.json'.'

When i navigate to the Debug folder, it seems that my folder containing my json files is not there. The path is correct as far as I can see, but I don't think my json files are being added when the project builds.

The folder/files **are** included in the project.

How do I make sure that this folder I created is being included when the project is built?

Comment: Please update your question to include the `Properties` of that file (from Visual Studio) - preferably as a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)

Comment: Is \Folder\file.json included in your solution? What is its Copy to Output Directory property?

Comment: Please show the screenshot of the `Properties` from Visual Studio. At the very least I'd expect to see a `Build Action` as well.

Comment: Mark the json file in your source code as "Copy to output directory" as "always" .  This should resolve your issue.

Comment: When i checked the properties, I did need to set copy to output directory. That was my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the file properties to copy the content to the output directory? Check the attached image.

[image: Copy to Output Directory]