# GetDirectory returns wrong path of Debug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Excel VSTO Workbook's set debug path is `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Testing\Excel Stuff\VSTO\Debug\`

I am attempting to add an `appsettings.json` file to unity

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

    MessageBox.Show(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); // Trying to see what the directory is here

    container.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(config);

    // Logging
    container.RegisterType<ILogWriter, TextLogger>();
    container.RegisterType<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();

    // Set up Context
    container.RegisterInstance<FinanceDWEntities>(new FinanceDWEntities());
    container.Resolve<MainService>();
}
```

When I have the `MessageBox` show the current directory, however, it only displays: `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop`, which would explain why my `appsettings` information is coming back null, however why is `GetCurrentDirectory` not returning the full Debug path?

Comment: Is this really `Unity3d` specific or rather a general `c#` question? If this is really for Unity then you should in general probably rather use [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041505/559144 you should use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: This is what I found as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

current directory is different from original directory (which is what you want.)  You can try AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.  This is the directory the assembler probes for assemblies (bin in most cases.)

alternatively, since you are running an app on a desktop:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath?view=netframework-4.8