# Getting image path from Project folder in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to access my folder that contains Image files.
The folder is located inside my project. Here is the look on my Explorer:

[[image: 1]]

I am not able to access it through code when I do the following: `Vanilla_Icons_Installer.Images`.

How can I access `Image1.png` inside `Images` folder by doing `PreviewPicture.Image = path`?

Comment: When and for what purpose do you do it? The folder structure at the time of development project does not cooperate with the time of execution. If you want to get the folder location in the source code of your program, you need to design the folder structure after installation and deployment and code accordingly. It is also possible to build the configuration during debugging, or to give information from the outside using a configuration file or the like.

Comment: Provide some code, which you use for access image. And what do you mean by access image? Do you want image path or read image ?

Comment: Otherwise, these articles will be helpful for project settings such as builds. [Set compiler and build properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-160), [Common macros for MSBuild commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path . hope it's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **WPF** you can use a *relative path* inside your XAML like this:

```
<Image x:Key="Image" Source="../Images/Image1.png" />
```

But in your screenshot I see that you are using **WinForms** and you want to set it through code.
Therefore you could try this:

```
PreviewPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(
  Path.Combine (
     Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
     "Images/Image1.png"));
```

Don't forget to set the `Copy to Output directory` option to e.x. "Copy if newer" for your Image file.
The above code will create a Images directory in your *bin/debug* folder with the image inside.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to error (I tried it in my program).

Comment: Alright, I will test it myself and let you know.

Comment: @Jermartyno I forgot the .png **file extension** in my code above. When you also set the Copy to Output directory option like you mentioned in your answer, this code works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this fixed my problem:

PreviewPicture.Image = `Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images", "LightColorful", "ClassImages.png"));`

And setting the Copy to Output property of Image to Copy if newer.

Comment: Sounds great! What about my suggestion?