# Finding a xml config file

Tags: c#, filepath, file-exists

I am trying to check whether an xml config file exists.

The file has the name MyApp.exe.config

I am using

```
public static bool FileExistsCheck(string filename, string filepath = "")
{
    if (filepath.Length == 0)
        filepath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    return File.Exists(filepath + "\\" + filename);
}
```

this returns `false` despite the file existing

Can anyone advise on the correct way of checking whether or not this file exists?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295687/get-path-to-execution-directory-of-windows-forms-application

Comment: why do you need to know? Perhaps there is another way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
return File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

at runtime `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will return debug/release/bin dir path. Does the config XML file reside in those folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for File.Exists(CONFIGFILENAME). Because .net takes the relativ path from the current directory

Answer (score 0):

For first I recommend you to use `Path.Combine(path, fileName);` to create paths.

For second use `Application.StartupPath`, not `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`.

For third, make sure that your application folder contains `MyApp.exe.config`.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this method:

```
public static bool isFileExist(string filePath)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

I think the culprit on your method is this:

```
filepath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```