# Change PictureBox image to images from application folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, picturebox

I want `PictureBox` to load images from application folder. In the code below it loads picture from exact place. I want it to load images from application's folder so that if I copy it to other computers it could load images.

How can I do it?

Loads from exact place:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\68.jpg");
```

I want it to be like this:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("ApplicationFolder\68.jpg");
```

Comment: You want the AppDomain's current base directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295687/get-path-to-execution-directory-of-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 4):

Using the info in the comment above, you could do:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "68.jpg"))
```

To do use a subdirectory of the assembly base directory:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "SomeFolderInBaseDirectory", "68.jpg"))
```

Comment: Thanks.It works.Also I wanted to ask if I can call images from folder inside the BaseDirectory so that they don't mix with .exe files?

Comment: @MuradTalibov Please accept as answer if it solved your issue (which according to your comment it did).

Answer (score 0):

Use to keep images in application resources:

Add PictureBox control on Form. Select the control on the form and use properties.
Find Image under the Appearance section in Properties tab and click on [...].
Select Resource dialog imports all images you're going to use in your application.
Then remove the PictureBox from the Form. The application keeps all images in resources