# Where can I find the rootfolder for my VB.net project

Tags: vb.net

I am making a project that will be put on a disc to use. This means that all of the files that I call upon have to be on that disc. How and where do I put my files to ensure that they will stay with the project? Does it go in the bin folder? And when I am calling on that file what file path do I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295687/get-path-to-execution-directory-of-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 0):

In general, the bin folder is not a place you should be storing anything that you want to persist with the project.

When you build, Visual Studio will copy the files needed to run the program into the bin folder, such as libraries and web.config or app.config files.

For other files you want included, add them to your project and set their [build action property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to *Content*:

> **Content** - The file is not compiled, but is included in the Content output group.
>   For example, this setting is the default value for an .htm or other
>   kind of Web file.