# Picture box Image Directory Does not Run Another Computer

Tags: c#, image, file-upload, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

i crated a Picturebox in windows form.This code below is working properly

```
PictureBox.ImageLocation=@"C:\Users\MyPc\Desktop\Project\Image.jpg
```

but When i run my code in another pc the image doesn't shown cause of its directory.I have to change the pc name.How can I do this in a more general way without chancing the name?

Comment: Use a relative path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/295694/3279876

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get path to execution directory of Windows Forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295687/get-path-to-execution-directory-of-windows-forms-application)

Comment: [relative path](https://networkencyclopedia.com/relative-path/#:~:text=Traditional%20DOS%20Path%20%20%20%20Path%20,directory%20t%20...%20%202%20more%20rows%20)

Comment: _.I have to change the pc name._ Meaning what?

Answer (score 0):

You sould use the following method to determine the user's desktop folder:

```cs
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

and maybe the best way for having a correct path is also using System.IO.Path.Combine() method:

```cs
PictureBox.ImageLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Project", "Image.jpg"));
```